# How to convert object[,] to datatable in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, excel, casting

I am reading data from excel file using **Interop lib.** I am able to connect to the excel and read data from it.

I am getitng the return type as object[,]. I am not sure what exactly it specifies. I am aware of object[] which is array of objects.

Not sure of `object[,]` . I tried googling but did not find any useful explanations.

Further, i would like to convert  this to datatable and bind it to a data grid view in winforms.

**Do we need to convert above array to datatable before binding or is there any other way to bind it to grid ?**

*Please give me some thoughts to get heads up.*

**Please find below code :**

```
void ReadSheetData(string strFilePath)
        {

            Workbook workBook = _excelApp.Workbooks.Open(strFilePath,
            Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
            Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
            Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
            Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

            int numSheets = workBook.Sheets.Count;

            for (int sheetNum = 1; sheetNum < numSheets + 1; sheetNum++)
            {

                Worksheet sheet = (Worksheet)workBook.Sheets[sheetNum];
                Range excelRange = sheet.UsedRange;
                object[,] valueArray = (object[,])excelRange.get_Value(XlRangeValueDataType.xlRangeValueDefault);
                PrepareData(valueArray);
            }
        }

System.Data.DataTable PrepareData(object[,] valueArray)
    {
        System.Data.DataTable dtTemp = new System.Data.DataTable();
        dtTemp=????? // How to convert object[,] to datatable
        return dtTemp;
    }
```

Comment: Use EPPLUS the library is free, can read / write xlsx files, is magnitudes faster than Interop, more stable and converting to a datatable is the simple command ToDataTable().

Comment: Yes..you are correct..we would like to have no external dependencies..that is reason of not using oledb connection also

Comment: For my personal experience frequently use reading EXCLE and import data. 
What you want to do it is advisable to solve it by creating a type of class that represents the record of your Excel, load an array of your data. 
When you have an array of data, you can do what you want. If you want I'll put you in the solution as I do

Comment: there is no restriction on what type of data can be present in the excel. So, it has ro be dynamic and should accept any excel sheet. I will not know what class to create since i am unware of data in the excel

Comment: @SaiAvinash Excel IS an external dependency, and a quite heavy one too. Furthermore, you cannot really control excel to the extent you need. Maybe it is not installed, maybe an old / new version is installed who behaves differently. Maybe it balks to some reason (file on untrusted network share which creates an security dialog?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enumerating the rows and the columns using first index and second index array length.

```
var rowCount = valueArray.GetLength(0);
var columnCount = valueArray.GetLength(1);

var dtTemp = new DataTable();
foreach(var c in Enumerable.Range(1, columnCount))
    dtTemp.Columns.Add();
foreach (var r in Enumerable.Range(1, rowCount))
    dtTemp.Rows.Add(Enumerable.Range(1, columnCount)
        .Select(c => valueArray[r - 1, c - 1]).ToArray());
```

Comment: Error 5 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<int>' does not contain a definition for 'Select' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Select<TSource,TResult>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, System.Func<TSource,TResult>)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: @SaiAvinash, I just realized I'm using an extension method `Each`, I just changed it to use foreach, it should work now

Comment: Still there is some problem. I could see that the entire table is filled with same value

Comment: Sry..its my mistake ..its working great now. the date fields are converted into float values. Any suggestions ? Thank you !